# Azure Adal B2C GA Release

Tags: android, azure, release, adal, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any release available for azure adal b2c GA. As of know i think GA version is available for B2B not for B2C. The document shows the version 2.0.3-alpha.

Here is the link
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/tree/convergence

Answer (score 1):

There is no GA library available for B2C. The work is in progress to get a preview out for Android. To get an idea of the surface area you could expect, check out https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet